# How do I start auto recording a video in iPhone Sdk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, video, recording

Hi I am working on a application which requires the recroding action for the camera of the iPhone 3GS to start recording a video directly.. 
Earlier I have done this screwing up the UIImagePicker and using CGGraphicContext to get images but that was for a single image. Is there a possibility of triggering the vedio recording directly. 
What does the method start recording do that is exposed I tried using it but nothing happens actually. 
The other solution I was think was to trigger a timer and capture images and the combine them into a video

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy with AVFoundation. 
Just take a look [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/199507#199507) and documentationabout AVFoundation, AVCapture, sessions, etc.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/199507#199507
(you need to log in to iPhone dev center)

Hope this helps